# Centered average of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to compute the "centered" average of an array of ints. This is defined as the mean the values ignoring the largest and smallest values in the array. If there are multiple copies of the smallest or largest value, ignore just one copy.

How do I deal with duplicate max and min values? Here is the code that I have so far.

```py
total = 0
i = 0
for i in range(i,len(nums)-1) :
    total += nums[i]
return (total- max(nums) - min(nums)) / (len(nums)-2)
```

Comment: Your indentation as shown here is wrong, please correct it. What you want is just `(sum(nums) - max(nums) - min(nums)) // (len(nums) - 2)`, substracting the max and min like this already takes care of removing only one of possible duplicate values. Is there any other constraint that you have to respect?

Comment: is there any way to use this method instead of sum(nums). Ur code works :)

Comment: If you're not allowed to use `sum`, are you allowed to use `min`, `max` and `len`?

Comment: Don't use `max` or `min`, as these require you iterating over the list you *just* finished iterating over.

Comment: That said, a few iterations by *built-in* functions may be faster than multiple operations in the body of a single loop. Just use `total = sum(nums)`.

Comment: thanks :) just trying to understand why my code was wrong

Comment: Use `for i in range(0, len(nums))`, as the upper bound of the range is excluded. Also, it is better to do `for num in nums: total += num` rather than using indices.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by combining sorting and list indexing. Sorting puts the list in ascending order. Now an index of [1:] will skip the first element (the minimum in the list) and an index of [:-1] will skip the last element (the maximum in the list). Combine these then compute the mean of the list to get the centered average.

```py
from statistics import mean

l = [15, 9, 55, 41, 35, 20, 62, 49] 
l.sort()
mean(l[1:-1])
```

Result:

```py
35.833333333333336
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you elaborate a little bit more about what you want to achieve with your exercise? In any case, you can use the module `mean()` from the statistics package to calculate the mean value in a given list, like this:

```
from statistics import mean 

lst = [15, 9, 55, 41, 35, 20, 62, 49]
lst.sort()
mean(lst[1:-1])
```

Comment: The question explicitely states that one instance of the smallest and largest value must be excluded, which your code absolutely doesn't do...